# Troubleshooting touchscreen

Tags: x11, xorg, mouse, touch-screen

I am trying to use a touchscreen monitor (Dell e2014t).  `Dmesg` shows it finding it

```
[    8.624433] usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0408, idProduct=3025, bcdDevice= 0.39
[    8.624441] usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    8.624447] usb 1-1.1.3: Product: HID-TQH-FS
[    8.624453] usb 1-1.1.3: Manufacturer: Quanta
[    8.624459] usb 1-1.1.3: SerialNumber: TQHM133302NU
[    8.643385] input: Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0/0003:0408:3025.0003/input/input4
[    8.643688] input: Quanta HID-TQH-FS as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0/0003:0408:3025.0003/input/input5
[    8.643993] hid-multitouch 0003:0408:3025.0003: input,hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Quanta HID-TQH-FS] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.3/input0
[    8.652270] hid-generic 0003:0408:3025.0004: hiddev97,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Quanta HID-TQH-FS] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1.3/input1
```

When I use evtest I see the devices but nothing happens when I touch the screen.  I thought the issue was the hardware so I got my hands on a second one, same problem.

Here is the log from xorg:

```
[    31.324] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse (/dev/input/event0)
[    31.324] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    31.324] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    31.324] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    31.326] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    31.371] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    31.371]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 0.28.2
[    31.371]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    31.371]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    31.371] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse'
[    31.440] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 18 paused 0
[    31.441] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: always reports core events
[    31.441] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    31.441] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    31.514] (II) event0  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    31.515] (II) event0  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: device is a pointer
[    31.516] (II) event0  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: device removed
[    31.516] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0/0003:0408:3025.0003/input/input4/event0"
[    31.516] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 6)
[    31.517] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    31.517] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    31.517] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    31.517] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    31.525] (II) event0  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    31.527] (II) event0  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse: device is a pointer
[    31.533] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Quanta HID-TQH-FS Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    31.534] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    31.534] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    31.538] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Quanta HID-TQH-FS (/dev/input/event1)
[    31.538] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[    31.538] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS: Applying InputClass "libinput touchscreen catchall"
[    31.538] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Quanta HID-TQH-FS'
[    31.541] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 21 paused 0
[    31.541] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS: always reports core events
[    31.541] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    31.541] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    31.554] (II) event1  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[    31.554] (II) event1  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS: device is a touch device
[    31.555] (II) event1  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS: device removed
[    31.555] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3/1-1.1.3:1.0/0003:0408:3025.0003/input/input5/event1"
[    31.555] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Quanta HID-TQH-FS" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 7)
[    31.556] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    31.556] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    31.556] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    31.556] (**) Quanta HID-TQH-FS: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    31.567] (II) event1  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS: is tagged by udev as: Touchscreen
[    31.568] (II) event1  - Quanta HID-TQH-FS: device is a touch device
[    31.573] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Quanta HID-TQH-FS (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    31.573] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    31.573] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Comment: Which DE/WM are you using?

Comment: I am using open box on a raspberry pi. I I was trying to setup a kiosk style self service app.

Comment: Just so I understand would the desktop environment effect what I see via  cat /dev/input/event?